UTF-7 Decoding Produces Incorrect Characters in Qt Application
I'm working on a Qt-based text editor and attempting to decode text encoded in UTF-7. However, I'm encountering an issue where decoded characters are incorrect. For example, decoding the text Hello, +Z1TA- (UTF-7 representation of Hello, 世界) results in Hello, ᙎ䱵.
I've implemented the decoding logic in a class InterpreteAsUtf7, but it seems there is an issue with how I'm processing Base64 segments or converting them to UTF-16.
Here is a simple application demonstrating the problem. The hardcoded UTF-7 encoded string ("Hello, +Z1TA-") should decode to "Hello, 世界", but it doesn't. Can someone help identify what's wrong with the decoding logic?
#include <QString>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

class InterpreteAsUtf7 {
public:
    static QString decodeUtf7(const QByteArray& utf7Data);

private:
    static QString processBase64Segment(const QByteArray& base64Buffer, bool& errorFlag);
    static QString convertToUtf16LE(const QByteArray& decodedBytes, bool& errorFlag);
};

QString InterpreteAsUtf7::decodeUtf7(const QByteArray& utf7Data) {
    QString result;
    QByteArray base64Buffer;
    bool inBase64 = false;
    bool decodingError = false;

    for (char c : utf7Data) {
        if (c == '+') {
            if (inBase64) {
                result += "+" + base64Buffer;  // Unclosed Base64 section treated as literal
                base64Buffer.clear();
            }
            inBase64 = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (c == '-' && inBase64) {
            result += processBase64Segment(base64Buffer, decodingError);
            base64Buffer.clear();
            inBase64 = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (inBase64) {
            base64Buffer.append(c);
        } else {
            result += QChar(c);  // Literal character
        }
    }

    if (inBase64) {
        result += "+" + base64Buffer;  // Unclosed Base64 treated as literal
    }

    return result;
}

QString InterpreteAsUtf7::processBase64Segment(const QByteArray& base64Buffer, bool& errorFlag) {
    QByteArray decodedBytes = QByteArray::fromBase64(base64Buffer);
    if (decodedBytes.isEmpty()) {
        errorFlag = true;
        qWarning() << "[WARNING] Base64 decoding failed for:" << base64Buffer;
        return QString();
    }
    return convertToUtf16LE(decodedBytes, errorFlag);
}

QString InterpreteAsUtf7::convertToUtf16LE(const QByteArray& decodedBytes, bool& errorFlag) {
    if (decodedBytes.size() % 2 != 0) {
        errorFlag = true;
        qWarning() << "[WARNING] Decoded bytes not aligned for UTF-16:" << decodedBytes;
        return QString();
    }

    QString result;
    for (int i = 0; i < decodedBytes.size(); i += 2) {
        ushort codeUnit = static_cast<uchar>(decodedBytes[i]) |
                          (static_cast<uchar>(decodedBytes[i + 1]) << 8);
        result.append(QChar(codeUnit));
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    QByteArray utf7Data = "Hello, +Z1TA-";  // UTF-7 encoded string for "Hello, 世界"
    QString decodedText = InterpreteAsUtf7::decodeUtf7(utf7Data);

    qDebug() << "Original UTF-7:" << utf7Data;
    qDebug() << "Decoded UTF-7:" << decodedText;

    return 0;
}


Encoded 世界 should be either ThZ1TA (UTF-16BE -> base64) or Fk5MdQ (UTF-16LE -> base64), not Z1TA.
In wikipedia utf-7 article is correct ! becomes ACE, which means we should use UTF-16BE
QByteArray utf7Data = "Hello, +ThZ1TA-";

Thats how I found out (git bash shell or linux):
echo -n 世界 | iconv -t UTF-16BE | base64
echo -n 世界 | iconv -t UTF-16LE | base64
echo -n '!' | iconv -t UTF-16BE | base64

Qt uses UTF-16LE for internal string representation1, which means that if we use UTF-16BE in encoder we need to flip bytes in decoder to get our string back.
Like this:
ushort codeUnit = static_cast<uchar>(decodedBytes[i + 1]) |
                          (static_cast<uchar>(decodedBytes[i]) << 8);

Or we can use BOM and QString::fromUtf16 to flip it:
QString InterpreteAsUtf7::convertToUtf16LE(const QByteArray& decodedBytes, bool& errorFlag) {
    if (decodedBytes.size() % 2 != 0) {
        errorFlag = true;
        qWarning() << "[WARNING] Decoded bytes not aligned for UTF-16:" << decodedBytes;
        return QString();
    }
    QByteArray data = "\xfe\xff" + decodedBytes + QByteArray("\0\0", 2);
    QString result = QString::fromUtf16((const char16_t *) data.data());
    return result;
}

1 acutally it uses array of char16_t, but since x86 and x86_64 is little endian, array of char16_t represented as byte array will be little endian, as far as I understand.

Using Qt6 configured and linked against icu library (-DFEATURE_icu=ON) you can do this:
#include <QStringConverter>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString s = "Hello, 世界 ";
    auto encoder = QStringEncoder("utf-7");
    QByteArray data = encoder(s);

    // prints "Hello, +ThZ1TA "
    std::cout << QString::fromUtf8(data.data()).toStdString().c_str() << "\n";

    auto decoder = QStringDecoder("utf-7");
    QString s2 = decoder(data);

    // prints "Hello, 世界 "
    std::cout << s2.toStdString().c_str() << "\n";

    return 0;
}

It doesn't work correctly without space at the end of the string, though (probably needs non-base64 block at the end).
